# Аналитика FlurrySDK - существуют ли Best practices?

Tags: ios

Всем привет!

Второй раз сталкиваюсь с необходимостью установки Flurry-аналитики в приложение, которым в настоящее время занимаюсь.

На очереди 40 ивентов вида

```
Event Name - Application/Launched 
When this should be triggered? - as soon as the app is finished loading and displayed to the user
Parameters to capture, if available (All requests should include: app_version)
```

которые нужно раскидать по приложению, и это минимум половина от того, что нужно будет добавлять позже.

Я уже давно знаком с разделами вводной документации Flurry "Getting Started": [Step 2 - Custom Events](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Events&utm_source=hs_automation&utm_medium=email&utm_content=10812770&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-85Lon1psI2vKWCMwU2lnxWcrcYZjaJYNIb37uoAMkUhTL8Qe0nm6DZopa4RlqPPopgJTdxhSuyWiXn6SE9UFpQX7MQQA&_hsmi=10812770) и [Step 3 - Advanced features](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart), так что суть того, как работать с API, которые предоставляет Flurry, мне понятна. Вопрос в том, как грамотно все это организовать, а именно:

**Вопрос в следующем:**

40 ивентов это 40+ строк вида

```
[MyAnalyticsManager sendEvent: @"Some Event Name" params: @ {@"key1" : @"value1", @"key2": @"value2" }];

или если напрямую:

[Flurry logEvent:@"Article_Read"];

или вроде:
[Flurry logEvent:@"Article_Read" withParameters:articleParams timed:YES];
...
[Flurry endTimedEvent:@"Article_Read" withParameters:nil];
```

Которые по большей части нужно будет расставить в методы жизненного цикла UIViewController вроде viewDidAppear: или в его же IBAction'ы вроде backButtonPressed:, saveButtonPressed: итп., откуда последует несметное количество строк, разбросанных по всему приложению в UIViewController'ах, которые в идеале как будто должны были бы, как ни в чем не бывало, заниматься своими житейскими обязанностями: рендерингом UI-элементов, IBActions итп. - то есть всем, чем угодно, но только не рассылкой ивентов в разные аналитики вроде Flurrry.

**Существует ли какой-то умный способ все это организовать как-то так, чтобы контроллеры оставались свободными от строк, посвященных аналитике, то есть event tracking?**

Как и во всех других своих вопросах, прошу развернутые ответы, описывающие реальный, живой опыт - у меня не было, и похоже, что нет времени, чтобы самому системно подойти к этому вопросу - может быть кто-то все-таки проработал этот вопрос до меня и за меня :) ?

P.S. Параллельно отправляю этот вопрос в твиттер и Objective-C чаты, которые знаю.

Спасибо!

---

**ARAnalytics**

"Тепло", но не "Горячо": документация [Orta/ARAnalytics](https://github.com/orta/ARAnalytics), ее раздел DSL как раз про попытку системного охвата определенной группы событий.

Вскрытие ARAnalytics показало мне, что там используется фреймворк Aspects (swizzling on steroids), с помощью которого они свиззлят селекторы UIViewController'ов и подменяют их блоками, указанными пользователем, так что получаются штуки вроде: [ARAnalytics DSL](https://github.com/orta/ARAnalytics#dsl).

Беглый обзор показывает, что проект сделан добротно, поэтому собираюсь его попробовать. Поэтому дополнительные вопросы к этому топику:

**Есть ли у кого-то опыт использования ARAnalytics?**

**Видит ли кто-то какие-либо проблемы в таком прямолинейном подходе, используемом ARAnalytics: свиззл viewDidAppear: и подмешивание к нему вызова кастомного блока (или свиззл селекторов вроде backButtonWasPressed:) и так на каждый из 40-100 ивентов?**

---

Интересной альтернативой грубому свиззлингу я вижу чуть менее, но все равно грубое проксирование: создание классов вроде UserListAnalytics для соответствующих им контроллерам UserListViewController, которые содержат соответствующие селекторы, на которые идет event tracking и подмешивание их через forwardInvocation & friends в UIViewController - в результате эти методы отрабатываются до или после оригинальных методов View Controller'а. Буду рад любым комментариям на эту тему.

Comment: Станислав, я бы посоветовал Вам посмотреть в сторону аналитического сервеса http://zeoinsight.com.
Как раз он решает все ваши проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Обязательно гляну.